# Call two functions at once

Tags: javascript

how would that code be calling the two functions together, but as parameters? It should show the week that got the most sales and how much was sold this week

```js
var store = [{
  "Week": 1
  "sales": 35
}, {
  "Week": 2
  "sales": 53
}, {
  "Week": 3
  "sales": 48
}, {
  "Week": 4
  "sales": 24
}];

var over-sell = 0;
var improvedweek;

function weeks(list) {
  for (var x in list) {
    if (list[x].Sales > over-sell) {
      over-sell = list[x].sales;
      improvedweek = list[x].week;
    }
  }
  return improvedweek;
}

function sales(list) {
  for (var y in list) {
    if (store[y].Sales > over-sell) {
      sale = list[y].sales;
    }
  }
  return over-sell;
}
improvedweek = weeks (store);
over-sell = sales (store);
  alert("the week of highest sale was " + improvedweek + ", with " + over-sell + " sales");
}
```

would there be any way to do it with the JS function only, without using html?

Comment: `over-sell` is not a valid Javascript variable name. It contains an operator `-`.

Comment: Please indent - it's hard to follow.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "without using html." There is no HTML in the code you presented.

Comment: Welcome. It is also unclear from your current code example how you are using HTML at all. Please update your question to show how you are using HTML and what you mean by "using the JS function only".

Comment: You have a logical flaw in `sales()` by not accessing `list` yet `store`. Also `sale` in it is not really defined anywhere.

Comment: Pass both the values in one function and display the result from there .

Answer (score 0):

As I understood - this is what you want to get

```js
function weekAndSells (list) {
  var overSell = 0;
  var improvedweek;
  for (var x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
    if (list[x].sales > overSell) {
      overSell = list[x].sales;
      improvedweek = list[x].Week;
    }
  }
  return {
    overSell,
    improvedweek
  };
}

var improvedWeekAndOversell = weekAndSells(store);

alert(
  'the week of highest sale was ' +
  improvedWeekAndOversell.improvedweek +
  ', with ' +
  improvedWeekAndOversell.overSell +
  ' sales'
);
```